# Правильно ли расставил знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Список, Вика, - пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте! Знаки препинания расставлены не совсем корректорно. Уберите тире, и тогда предложение будет выглядеть лучше.

Правильная пунктуация: «Список, Вика, пожалуйста».

Объяснение.

Первая запятая ставится из-за наличия обращения, вторая — из-за вводного слова «пожалуйста», которое, находясь в конце предложения, выделяется одной запятой.